# Conflict with VPN client and SQL Server Express

Tags: windows, windows-10, sql-server-express

I have a Windows application running locally on a Windows 10 PC that connects to a SQL Server Express database that is also installed locally on the PC.  The PC also has a VPN client on it.  Whenever the VPN client is logged onto a network, the Windows application cannot connect to the SQL Server database.  So, I have to go into SQL Server Configuration Manager and change the setup from using TCP/IP to use Shared Memory.  Then everything works fine.  So, I assume both programs are using the TCP/IP stack and are conflicting with each other.  The VPN client is typically connected continuously all day.  Would anyone know why there would be a conflict here?  Thanks.

Comment: A VPN connects you to another network, but as a side effect it removes access to your local network.